# Codeigniter email sending is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to send an email with an codeigniter contact us form but its not sending the email.
Yes I know this question has been asked before but I just want to know if I don't have any wrong code.

This is my controller file (Contactform.php) :

```
<?php error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump"); 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>


<?php
class Contactform extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email'));
    }

    function index()
    {
      //set validation rules
      //$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_alpha_space_only');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'trim|required|valid_email');
       //$this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Subject', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
       //$this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        //run validation on form input
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            //validation fails
            $this->load->view('contact_form_view');
        }
        else
        {
            //get the form data
            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $from_email = $this->input->post('email');
            $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
            $message = $this->input->post('message');

            //zet to_email naar welk email je het contact form naar wilt laten sturen
            $to_email = 'ferran1004@gmail.com';

            //configure email settings
            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
            $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
            $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
            $config['smtp_user'] = 'ferra@gmail.com';
            $config['smtp_pass'] = 'tom10';
            $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
            $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
            $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
            $this->load->library('email', $config);
            $this->email->initialize($config);                        

            //send mail
            $this->email->from($from_email, $name);
            $this->email->to($to_email);
            $this->email->subject($subject);
            $this->email->message($message);
            if ($this->email->send())
            {
                // mail sent
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');
                redirect('contactform/index');
            }
            else
            {
                //error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">There is error in sending mail! Please try again later</div>');
                redirect('contactform/index');
            }
        }
    }

    //custom validation function to accept only alphabets and space input
    function alpha_space_only($str)
    {
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$str))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_space_only', 'The %s field must contain only alphabets and space');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And this is my view form file (contact_form_view.php):

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 well">
            <?php $attributes = array("class" => "form-horizontal", "name" => "Contactform");
            echo form_open("Contactform/index", $attributes);?>
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Contact Form</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" />
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('name'); ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="email" class="control-label">Email ID</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your Email ID" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" />
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="subject" class="control-label">Subject</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Your Subject" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('subject'); ?>" />
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('subject'); ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="message" class="control-label">Message</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="4" placeholder="Your Message"><?php echo set_value('message'); ?></textarea>
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('message'); ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send" />
                </div>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my email.php in my config folder: (I don't know if I need this file because I have the same code in my controller)

```
<?php
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; //change this
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com'; 
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxxxxxx'; 
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes to comply with RFC 822 standard

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you add `email.php` in config folder

```
<?php
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; //change this
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com'; 
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxxxxxx'; 
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes to comply with RFC 822 standard

?>
```

then auto load config and library in autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('email');

$autoload['config'] = array('email');
```

and you send mail using this

```
        $to_email = 'ferran1004@gmail.com';

        $message = "email message";

        $this->email->from('noreply@gmail.com','Admin');
        $this->email->to($to_email);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        if ($this->email->send() == TRUE)
        {
            log_message('debug', 'Email Send SuccessFully>>>>>>>>>>>');
        }
        else
        {
            log_message('debug', 'Email Not Send>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
        }
```

Comment: So I don't need to configure email settings in my controller file?

Comment: yes you not need in controller

Comment: also enable less secure app in your google account setting

Comment: and why do I need to use this: $this->email->from('noreply@gmail.com','Admin'); instead of this code: $this->email->from($from_email, $name);

Comment: yeah you can use this

Comment: @GopalBhuva when you mail sending multiple controll then you can define all controller ?? when futher change smtp then need change all controller its very hard this